# Ansible limit parameter is not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have my Ansible project structure like this:

[image]

My `appServers` under `hosts` contains my hosts as follows:

```
local ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1

staging ansible_ssh_host=<host_ip> ansible_connection=ssh  ansible_user=ubuntu  ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<key>

vara-dev ansible_ssh_host=<host ip> ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=varanet ansible_ssh_pass=<password>

[localhost]
local

[iquippo-staging]
staging

[varanet-server]
vara-dev

[target]
local
staging
vara-dev
```

But when I am trying this command:

```
ansible -i inventory/hosts/ --limit local -m ping
```

It is throwing this error:

```
ERROR! Missing target hosts
```

I am using http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html
 for `limit` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify any host group for the command, so Ansible reports the required parameter is missing.

See the result of:

```
ansible all -i inventory/hosts/ --limit local -m ping
```